# What is going on with MSE website access from phones.

Tags: bug, user-interface

As the title is rather ambiguous, I shall explain all here. For a while now, I tend to use both platforms phone and laptop, with both working absolutely fine. But today, it seems that there has been a change to my phone platform experience with the web page not resize correctly and cutting off answer box to the point where I can not even up vote? It seems rather clunky as well.

My question is, where does one find all planned updates? And is meta the ideal place to put my concerns? Finally, has anyone else experienced this?

Sorry for the rant (and even more if this misplaced)

The phone in question is an iPhone 5s (iOS 7.1.1) if that helps.

Thanks!

Also, if this question gets too many down votes I will remove out of sheer embarrassment! :)

Comment: Is it just MSE, or does it also affect SO and MO, for example?

Comment: Are you using the mobile interface from your phone? If you do, try scrolling down and look for "full site" somewhere on the bottom of the page. Click it and see what happens.

Comment: @mixedmath it seems to sporadic but still quite annoying. I cannot be absolutely sure that it will be the same issue on SO, and MO. But given, that is the same sort of layout I do not see why not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you. I know that I can go full site, but due to the nature of the site it is much better to access with the mobile site. Though I will edit the question to factor in that is iOS so that may be the cause.

Comment: I was going after two types of potential problem. MO also uses MathJax extensively, so if this is a MathJax related problem it would appear there (and not on SO). If it also occurs on SO, then it's above my paygrade (come to think of it, a *whole lot* is above my paygrade).

Comment: @mixedmath it seems I can type mathjax fairly ok still, but it just the re-sizing of the answers e.g. I deleted my answer, and then I went to upvote another answer on the same page, but due to the page not re-sizing I could not see the upvote banner on the side. Admiringly, this has happened fairly infrequently, but I know when I deploy an update it is good to get an idea of whats gone wrong. Though, this could get slightly annoying if it persists. Anyway, if it is above your payscale, I thank you for all your work on this site :)! Cheers for taking a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[New version of the mobile website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237518/259867) came out today. If you experience a bug that is not yet 
reported on [Über-Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), post it there, tagging [bug](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) and [mobile-web](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-web). Try to describe the problem more precisely, and include a screenshot along with the phone model and OS.

Comment: cheers. I will take a look and post a screenshot when it happens again. Should, I still post in the meantime? cheers.

Comment: @Chinny84 I'm not sure what you mean by *Should, I still post in the meantime?*. If you mean if it's okay to use the site from mobile phone, despite the bugs you experience, then yes. It's unlikely that your phone will explode if you do. :)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't so clear. I mean shall I post the bug as suggested in your answer (if it does not exist already)? or shall i wait until I experience the issue again?

Comment: @Chinny84 Better to wait until you have evidence. If it never appears again, problem solved...

Comment: Fair play. Not a lot I can say to that awesome logic :). Thanks again for your answer, and for pointing out a new area to scan through!